# Sql Server Management Studio does not have access to a .bak file on a remote server

Tags: sql-server, docker, containers, restore

I'm trying to restore a database backup that is on a server. This server is on a remote machine and runs in a docker container. The container OS is Ubuntu 20.04.
I can access the database, make queries on the master, etc. But when restoring the database, the .bak file is not visible to Sql Server Management Studio.
How do I solve this problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you type `*.*` in the `Nome do arquivo` (`File Name`) textbox and hit enter, do you see any files listed after that?

Comment: I can list the files when I select the "All Files" option in the checkbox next to it. But the .bak file still doesn't appear.

Comment: And you do see the same files as your command window (other than the .bak file)?...e.g. `Entropy.bin`?

Answer (score 1):

The restore wizard is not using your permission for local or remote folders but it uses the SQL Server account permissions.
You need to give SQL Server Engine service account proper rights to reach that network location.